# Combo Box, More Than One Item In A Row

Tags: wpf, combobox, expression-blend

I'm adding image items to a ComboBox, as you know ComboBox shows just one item in a row, but I want my combo to show more than one, and show images like they are all beside each other with a little space around them, so the user can pick one...

Any Help is pretty much appreciated...

Comment: ComboBox with more items in a row? That's going to confuse your users a lot, don't do that.

Comment: @svik: users are used to being confused. Look at some of the comboboxes (drop down thingies) in Word.

Comment: Poona, is 1 row still 1 item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the [`ComboBox.ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) to a [`WrapPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to edit the ItemTemplate and the ItemsPanel.

Right click the combobox and select *Edit Aditional Template* --> *Edit Generated Items* --> *Create Empty*

[image: Edit ItemTemplate]

Add an image and a text to a Vertical StackPanel in the template and set the bindings.

[image: Editing the ItemTemplate]

Now leave the template editing and right click the combobox again.

This time go to *Edit Aditional Template* --> *Edit Layout of Items* --> *Edit a Copy*

[image: Edit ItemsPanel]

Change the StackPanel to a *UniformGrid* and set the Columns property of this to 2.

The result should look a little like this:

[image: result]

I used sample data in this example. 2 properties: one image, one String(Name).